# Return type of a file for Swagger documentation with dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using [Swagger for dotnet core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?tabs=visual-studio) to document my dotnet core Web API.

I've read the documentation telling me that I need to add 
`[ProducesResponseType(typeof(XXXXX),200)]` above the controller methods to help swagger determine the response type of the method.

I've got a controller method that returns a file and i'm trying to work out how I can tell swagger i'm returning a file.

```
public class DocumentController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDocumentService _documentService;

    public DocumentController(IDocumentService documentService)
    {
        _documentService = documentService;
    }

    [HttpGet("{documentId}", Name= DocumentRoutes.Document)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(XXXXX), 200)] // <== What goes here?
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDocument(Guid documentId)
    {
        DocumentAdto documentAdto = await _documentService.GetAsync(documentId);
        return File(documentAdto.DocumentBytes, documentAdto.ContentType, documentAdto.Name);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

I've thought about byte[] but that just says the return type is "byte".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you need is the [`ProducesAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.producesattribute) and specify the content type as the parameter (e.g. "application/pdf" for a PDF file).

Edit: it appears Swagger may not pick up on the `ProducesAttribute`.  My suggestion would then be to leave the `Type` unset for `ProducesResponseType` and add a `/// <response code="200">Returns the requested file</response>` comment to the method.

Comment: do you think you can specify all content types?

Comment: I've just tried this and it doesn't look to have worked with the aspnetcore version of swashbuckle.

Comment: Returning a file is a response is a content type, not a `ProducesResponseType` which would signify a json or xml document schema.  If Swagger does not pick up on the `ProducesAttribute` on the action method, then I would simply leave the `Type` for `ProducesResponseType` unset and use a `<response code="200">Returns the requested file</response>` comment